# UFPS + Modern Ruins = Player is passing through wall

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

first of all, i'm new to the world of Unity Game Development but i do have an established experience in working with C#. I'm working with [UFPS](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/templates/systems/ufps-ultimate-fps-2943) out-of-the-box using [Modern Ruins](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/environments/industrial/modern-ruins-4136)' Demo Scene as the primary map. And for some reason, the default player (HeroHDWeapons) is passing through each and every objects on the map: walls, posts, literally everything.

However, i also have a humanoid asset for use on my AI/BOT using [Low Poly Soldiers](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/humanoids/low-poly-soldiers-53612), also out-of-the-box, and i just added a Capsule Collider, yet he doesn't pass through wall - or maybe since he's using a Nav Mesh Agent for his movement.

I've tried everything i know for my Player model based on what i've learned from basic unity tutorials. I added a RigidBody Component, which makes my player fall off the map with the "Use Gravity" option ticked but regardless, still passes through walls. I also tried adding a Capsule Collider, still passes through.

I did try adding a Capsule Collider on one of the objects on the map, and the player suddenly stopped passing through it. Of course, adding a Collider Component on each and every object on the map is not a good idea - considering there are multiple hundreds of them.

Here is the player model's properties:
[image]

P.S.: i've already done my fair share of research but none of them works. except for those talking about using other syntax like `Rigidbody.MovePosition(Vector3)` as i don't know what it would impact on the entire UFPS Framework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Character fall through ground after playing sometime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546971/character-fall-through-ground-after-playing-sometime)

Comment: you cant expect to detect a collision with anything that does not have a collider. simple as that. my advice is add colliders to big objects and level objects, but not all the clutter. stuff like walls, barrels, crates, the obvious big objects.

Comment: @Ruzihm no it is not a duplicate, i do not fall off the ground. its just that the player is passing through walls.

Comment: well that's nasty @Vanethrane, guess the only way around is to put colliders in the map objects? there's literally many of them.

Comment: @Nii It's a possible duplicate because the same answers to that question address yours as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need Colliders. Simple as that. pick and choose what objects to collide if it makes it easier. note that the unity Engine can ONLY handle 65536 different colliders at a time, only. lol.

According to the Unity3D documentation:

"Note that the PhysX engine used by Unity only handles a maximum of 65536 colliders in a scene."